# How to make the background black in Blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, software-design

I'm developing my first BlackBerry application and I want to change the background to Black and all the text (in `BasicEditField` labels, `Label`s, etc) White.

I tried using `setBackground(Background bg)` method on a `VerticalFieldManager`, but it only blackened the screen as far as my components goes. That is, if I have *only* two buttons one below the other, the background is only Black as far as the end of buttons. So when there is less components on screen, the screen is half black and half white.

Is there any way I can achieve the behavior I want:

- Whole screen should be **Black**.
- All the text labels should be **White**.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will set your background as black and editfield as white

```
VerticalFieldManager backg = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT){
public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
graphics.clear();
super.paint(graphics);
    }
};
```

Now add editfield as

```
EditField edit= new EditField("", "", 100, Field.FOCUSABLE){
protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
           g.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
           g.clear();
       }



backg.add(edit);
add(backg);
```

use `g.setColor(Color.WHITE);` for changing the font color.

Comment: g.setColor(Color.WHITE); will change the font color to white.

Comment: remove Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT from VerticalFieldManager. Then it will not scroll.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8702/discussion-between-signare-and-roshnal)

Answer (score 2):

Signare's version works for older versions, but there is another option as of OS 4.6. Check out the classes in the [net.rim.device.api.ui.decor](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/decor/package-summary.html) package.

I'm using this to change the background of the screen on one of my programs:

```
public class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

    MyScreen() {

        Background screenColor = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.Black);
        Manager backg= getMainManager();
        backg.setBackground(screenColor);

        EditField edit = new EditField("", "", 100, Field.FOCUSABLE){
            protected void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };
        Background fieldColor = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLACK);
        edit.setBackground(fieldColor);

        backg.add(edit);
    }
}
```

All of your fields have `.setBackround()` and `.setBorder()` methods, which let you make some nice customizations. I find this way easier than having to subclass all of my components just to change the background color. Unfortunately, you still have to do it to change the text color of an `EditField` or `LabelField`.

Comment: Yeah this method is much easier and neat. I'm developing for BlackBerry OS 6.0+ so it shouldn't be a problem. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: But any idea how to set the text color of `EditField`s to **White**?

Comment: I was searching yesterday, and I couldn't find any way other than subclassing the field, I've edited my response to include the updated code.